# Rename picture before uploading to Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

The selected picture from the user is **selectedImage**. My program uploads a user's picture under his unique nickname folder. E.g if david uploads a pic, it goes under "david" folder, but I want to be able to have the same filename for every picture uploaded. The goal: If david uploads 1 pic and then another pic, the 2nd one will replace the 1st one because they both have the same file name. I tried doing **renameTo** but instead it uploads under a new folder under  *david/imagename/old.jpg*

I want it to be like this *david/pic.jpg*  that's it. None of the solutions work for me:

```
public void uploadImage2(){
        String file_path = selectedImage.getLastPathSegment();
        File from = new File(file_path,"old");
        File to = new File("pic");
        from.renameTo(to);
        //create reference to images folder and assing a name to the file that will be uploaded
        imageRef = storageRef.child(getNickname() + "/" + from.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: So you're saying you want the exact same file name under nickname in the path for every upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work, it was simply writing

```
imageRef = storageRef.child(getNickname() + "/pic");
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, every time you upload a new picture to Firebase Storage, generate a unique id for each one beneath the user folder. To achieve this, you can simply use the push() method. From the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference):

> Create a reference to an auto-generated child location.

Comment: im not using firebase database, I just want to stay with storage

Comment: do I need to add database?

Comment: Yes, you need to store the urls in a Firebase database so you can later easely use them. There is no way to get all the image names within a folder in Firebase Storage.

Comment: I already have a way that every stores their picture under their unique nickname folder..the question is how to change the pic file name before it uploads to a fixed name that I want

Comment: Use the `push()` method, as explained in my answer. It will generate a new random unique key for each image.